# Изменение узла xml в php

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, simplexml

Есть xml вида

```
<users>
<user>
<login>123456</login>
<password>e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883eu4h3f7h4387hfqp</password>
<email>123456</email>
<name>d</name>
<key></key>
</user>
</users>
```

Узел key создан строкой

```
$key_xml = $user_xml->appendChild($xml->createElement('key'));
```

Я бы мог обратиться к узлу и записать в него через

```
$key_xml->appendChild($xml->createTextNode(null));
```

но записывать мне нужно в другом файле php. Как обратиться к узлу и записать/перезаписать в него что то?

Ах да, и нужно не просто обратиться к узлу, их будет много, и нужно обратиться к соответствующему, который входит в подмножество допустим с задаваемым емейлом.

```
$key_xml = $xml->xpath("//user[login = $login]/key") = 0;
```

Это работает отлично в случае поиска значения, при попытке записи "=0" выдает Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in.

```
$key_xml = $xml->xpath("//user[login = $login]/key");
$key_xml[0] = 'qqq'; $xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->save('users.xml');
```

не работает и выводит Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::save()

Comment: Пожалуйста, все ваши комментарии с кодами __перенесите в вопрос__. Под вопросом ссылка `править`, она там не зря находится.